# git command to get 50th revision of a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, github

I am having one file in git and committed many times. Now i have to find the 50th revision of that file in git. I tried a lot but i didn't get. So kingly help me with the git command.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$ git show HEAD~50:path/to/file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This....

> git revert HEAD~50: .HEAD